# References lost when compiling the project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-errors

I have a vb.net project. 
I have added some dlls as references in Project Property window and check the imported namespaces.

Then in any form I add "import X" command.

When I compile the project it says none of my references exists! 
Then when I close the project and reopen it, all my import lines recognize the references but as soon as I rebuild the projects all references lost and import lines don't recognize the references (although all my references are in Project property window)

any clue?

Comment: This sounds like a mismatch in the target framework of said projects. Can you check if there are any projects referencing others with a more recent framework?

Comment: I have had this exact same problem and it was because I hadn't also referenced all dependent assemblies. E.g. I add a reference to Assesmbly1.dll and it depends on Assembly2.dll but i hadn't also referenced Assembly2.dll.

Comment: The dll are from visual studio or from you?

Comment: @Conrad Clark : i have just one project in my solution. and i did not change my framework from the last successful compile.

Comment: @Ben Robinson: is there any simple way to find all references that are used in project? because its a big project, and i wrote it 2years age. it is to difficult to check import lines in all pages...

Comment: @Ibra: they are Dotnetnuke dlls.

Comment: Go to the property of each reference and make : copy local   -> true

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using VS2010.  Project + Properties, Application tab.  Change your Target framework setting, you cannot use the Client profile, you need the full version.

Answer (score -1):

Please try by marking True for Copy to Local Property of missing reference dll.

Comment: Expand references in Solution explorer then right click on the reference that a you are facing issue , click properties in that there is property Copy Local

Comment: the problem is that i don't have References in solution explorer!! i can just see references in Project Property\ References tab... how can i have references in solution bar?